# Setting X-Vault-Wrap-TTL header with spring-vault

Tags: http-headers, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

We are writing an application that creates short lived secrets using the "[response wrapping](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/response-wrapping.html)" feature of Vault. Vault API uses a header to [set the TTL to a non-default value](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/system/wrapping-wrap.html#wrapping-wrap).

Is there a way to set the `X-Vault-Wrap-TTL` header using spring-vault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Vault does not provide an API to create wrapped responses because it would require mirroring all API with a different response type. If you require response wrapping, then use the session callback:

```
ResponseEntity<VaultResponse> response = vaultOperations.doWithSession(restOperations -> {

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("X-Vault-Wrap-TTL", "1h");

    return restOperations.exchange("secret/mykey", HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(headers), VaultResponse.class);
});

Map<String, String> wrapInfo = response.getBody().getWrapInfo();

// token to unwrap the response
VaultToken token = VaultToken.of(wrapInfo.get("token"));
```