# Create a wrapped Token to access Hashicorp Vault | Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hashicorp-vault, spring-vault

I want to create a wrapped token programmatically from my Spring Boot application in order to read/write key-value pairs to/from Hashicorp vault. I have gone through the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-vault/docs/1.0.0.M2/api/index.html?org/springframework/vault/authentication/CubbyholeAuthentication.html).

Currently I am able to create a token having a TTL, use limit and a policy, but I did not find any option to wrap the token. I am using the following code to create the token:

```java
    private VaultTokenResponse getDefaultToken() {
        List<String> policies = Arrays.asList("default");
        VaultTokenRequest tokenRequest = VaultTokenRequest.builder()
                .ttl(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .numUses(10)
                .policies(policies)
                .renewable(true)
                .build();
        return VaultConfig.vaultTemplate.opsForToken().create(tokenRequest);
    }
```

Comment: After going through some SO posts, I found the solution mentioned in this SO post to be more convenient: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287024/setting-x-vault-wrap-ttl-header-with-spring-vault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use [VaultWrappingOperations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-vault/docs/current/api/org/springframework/vault/core/VaultWrappingOperations.html) on the token once you have created it.
Something like

```
VaultWrappingOperations operations = vaultOperations.opsForWrapping();
WrappedMetadata metadata = operations.wrap(map, Duration.ofMinutes(10));
metadata.getToken();
```